# Select a Selenium element based on text in nested tags

Tags: jquery, selenium

Im new to Selenium. This is my HTML code -

```
<a href="#">
   <span>Print</span>
</a>
```

Using Selenium, I would like to find the element `<a>` that contains `<span>` and within the `<span>`, the text - `"Print"`. There is only one such element on the page.

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[text()='Print']"))
```

The above code doesn't seem to work. How do I include `<span>` in the above code ?

The Jquery equivalent of what I am trying to achieve is - `$( "a > span:contains('Print')" )`

Please help!

Comment: As far as I am aware there is not currently a css selector for element content.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xpath to achieve this:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/span[text()='Print']"))
```

To make it more robust, in case span is not the immediate child of the a tag and the text can have leading trailing spaces/characters you can use:

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a//span[contains(text(),'Print')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this you can try

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("a")).findElement(By.tagName("span")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned OP there is no option yet in css selector to identify an element based on text value.

I would suggest use `XPATH`.

To identify the anchor tag based on child tag try following xpath options.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./span[text()='Print']]"))
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Print')]"))
```